# Why isn't every subset of a compact set also compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I've seen on MathSE that a subset of a compact set need not be compact. However, I am not fully understanding why.

If $X$ is compact then there exists a finite subcover, i.e., $X \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$. So any subset of $X$, say $K$, will be a subset of the finite union of $U_i$.

So why is not the case that $K$ is automatically compact?

Comment: But a cover of the subset need not cover the larger space.

Comment: Why does the cover of the subset need to cover the larger space?

Comment: Your argument above, if i'm interpreting it right, needs that.

Comment: I'm just going by defintions.

Comment: It is true that every closed subset of a compact space is compact, and that in a Hausdorff space (for example, a metric space), every compact subspace is closed.

Comment: Also I believe you are misunderstanding the definition. Compactness does not merely give "existence of a finite subcover." Indeed, *every* space has a finite subcover, namely itself. What compactness gives you is this: given *any* cover, there exists a finite *sub*cover.

Comment: So, you have to start with an (arbitrary) open cover of $K$ (not of $X$) and show that it has a finite subcover. But this can't be done in general, as the answers below show..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've shown is that any open cover $\mathcal{A}$ of $K$ has a finite subcover . . . **if** $\mathcal{A}$ is also a cover of $X$! But that need not happen. For a concrete example, consider $K=(0, 1)$ as a subset of $X=[0, 1]$. Then $\mathcal{A}=\{({1\over n}, 1-{1\over n}): n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a cover of $K$ with no finite subcover. Note that $\mathcal{A}$ fails to cover $X$, but there was no reason for it to cover $X$ in the first place.

Comment: So, you are saying I was only considering covers of $X$, but for $K$ to be compact we need to consider any arbitrary cover of $K$?

Comment: @AlJebr that is indeed what is being said here. A cover of $K$ need not cover $X$. Hence you may not be able to use compactness of $X$ to take a finite subcover of $K$, because compact of $X$ is only concerned with covers of $X$, but not all covers of $K$ cover $X$.

Comment: @AlJebr That's exactly it. Recall that "$K$ is compact" means "Every cover of $K$ by open sets has a finite subcover" - so we do indeed have to consider *arbitrary* open covers of $K$ (not just those which also happen to cover some other set $X$).

Answer (score 4):

An open cover of $K \subseteq X$ may not be an open cover of $X$. Indeed, for $K$ to be compact, you need to start with an open cover of $K$, not of $X$, and find a finite subcover.

Comment: Why does the cover of $K$ need to cover $X$? Isn't it the other way around?

Comment: It doesn't; this is exactly what I am saying. To prove $K$ is compact, you need to take an arbitrary cover $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of $K$ and find a finite subcover. In your reasoning above, you are saying you can take a finite subcover because $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ also covers $X$ and $X$ is compact. But it is not necessarily true that $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ also covers $X$, so this reasoning is flawed. Taking an open cover of $K$ which does not also cover $X$ (as @carmichael561 suggests above) shows that a subset of a compact set need not be compact.

Comment: You have to be careful though. If $K\subseteq X$ and has the $subspace$ topology, then a cover of $K$ is a collection $U_i\cap K$ s.t. $U_i \in \tau _X$. The point is that the $U_i$ may not cover $X$.

Comment: Suppose $X$ is compact. If $\mathcal U$ is a finite subcover of $X$, $X \subset \mathcal U$. So, $\mathcal U$ also covers $K$ and is finite. So doesn't it follow that $K \subset \mathcal U$ and thus is compact?

Comment: @AlJebr No. You're taking a particular open cover of $K$. You need the condition to hold for ANY open cover of $K$ (not only for those that cover $X$).

Answer (score 1):

Not every open cover of $K$ is an open cover of $X$. For instance, if $X=[0,1]$ and $K=(0,1)$ then $U_n=(1/n,1-1/n)$ is an open cover of $K$ but not $X$.

Answer (score 0):

"*Compactness*" is a finiteness condition for topological spaces which is infinitely more subtle than we are able to imagine. Note that the open unit disk $D\subset{\mathbb R}^2$, a standard metric space, would be compact according to your definition, since it is a subset of the compact square $Q:=[{-1},1]^2$, but you'll have to admit that $D$, considered as a subspace of ${\mathbb R}^2$ is not compact: The sequence ${\bf z}_n:=\bigl(1-{1\over n},0\bigr)$ $(n\geq1)$ in $D$ has no accumulation point in $D$.